# Hive SQL include 0 values in group by result

Tags: sql, group-by, hive

I have the following table in Hive:

```
account  day  type
a        1    X
b        1    Y
c        1    Z
a        2    Y
b        2    Z
c        3    Z
```

If I do the following SQL, I can generate this table:

```
SELECT day, type, count(distinct account) as account_count from my_table

day  type  account_count
1    X     1
1    Y     1
1    Z     1
2    Y     1
2    Z     1
3    Z     1
```

However, I would like to generate rows where the count is also `zero`, such that the table has the following structure:

```
day  type  account_count
1    X     1
1    Y     1
1    Z     1
2    X     0
2    Y     1
2    Z     1
3    X     0
3    Y     0
3    Z     1
```

Is it possible to generate this table structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to populate the values in the last column:

```
select d.day, t.type, count(distinct mt.type)
from (select distinct day from my_table) d cross join
     (select distinct type from my_table) t left join
     my_table my
     on mt.day = d.day and mt.type = d.type
group by d.date, t.type;
```

If the counts are always 0 or 1 (i.e. no duplicates), then this is more efficient:

```
select d.day, t.type, (case when mt.type is null then 0 else 1 end)
from (select distinct day from my_table) d cross join
     (select distinct type from my_table) t left join
     my_table my
     on mt.day = d.day and mt.type = d.type;
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I would need to do some kind of join with the ideal "template" table, but I did not think to use a `cross join`.